# Linux bash script, how to use the data in the command

Tags: linux

```
$script location1 location2
```

im new to linux and im trying to make a bash script that will move data, that will be used like a above, im just wondering how I would get those locations into a the script to work and tinker with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking, but if you want to access command line arguments in a bash script you can do so by using the variables $1 - $n. They are numbered in the order you passed them to the script.

See [here](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_read_command_line_arguments_in_a_bash_script) for some examples

Answer (score 0):

If you call the script using the command line

```
$ script location1 location2
```

you can access the value of the two arguments using `$1` and `$2`. That is, if you script looks like

```
from=$1
to=$2
echo "Move files from $from to $to"
```

the output resulting from the above command line would be

```
Move files from location1 to location2
```

Note that you don't need to set `from` and `to`; you can use `$1` and `$2` anywhere you would another variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use variables $1, $2, ...
for example, 
    $script location1 location2 
then in your script, you can get location1 as $1.

Here is a cool guide: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Special_Parameters_and_Variables

Answer (score 0):

Within your bash script you can simply use the "mv" command to move your data, like so:

**mv path/location1 path/location2**

That's it!

If, in your script you first go to the directory containing the location1 data, you won't need to provide the path on the first one, like so:

**cd path/**

**mv location1 path/location2**